# What am I doing wrong with Gruntjs targets?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I followed the instructions on the [grunt.option](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option) page to create different configurations for different environments/targets such as development, staging, and production in my Gruntfile. However, upon doing so I found that my tasks silently fail.

I've reduced the problem to a very simple example. The following Gruntfile fails to build the file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    less: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          compress: true
        },
        build: {
          src: ['src/css/test.less'],
          dest: 'build/css/test.css'
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less:dev']);
};
```

The output in my terminal is the following:

```
$ grunt
Running "less:dev" (less) task

Done, without errors.
```

If, however, I use the following Gruntfile, the build output is as expected:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    less: {
      options: {
        compress: true
      },
      build: {
        src: ['src/css/test.less'],
        dest: 'build/css/test.css'
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less']);
};
```

The terminal output for this Gruntfile reflects the built file:

```
$ grunt
Running "less:build" (less) task
File build/css/test.css created.

Done, without errors.
```

What am I doing wrong in the first Gruntfile? What is it that I am missing about this `task:target` convention?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first Gruntfile - If you want per-target options, you need to specify the `files` object. So your code would be something like this:

```
less: {
  dev: {
    files: {
      "build/css/test.css": "src/css/test.less"
    }
  },
  production: {
    options: {
      compress: true
    },
    files: {
      "build/css/test.css": "src/css/test.less"
    }
  },
}
```

Basically in your first Gruntfile `build` is an unknown object. Your target is named `dev` and `grunt-contrib-less` doesn't have an option called `build` so Grunt doesn't know where to write the files. Your second Gruntfile works because you set the options as a global. Use the above code if you want per-target options.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much for the concise explanation! :)

Comment: Thank you Ben, I just came here with this question too.  Was quite vexing, much appreciated.